# Pandas - Way to replace/merge rows with fewest steps

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm new to pandas so forgive me if I get the terminology wrong. I have searched but I'm not quite sure if I'm searching for the right thing, honestly all the different verbs confuse me.

This is probably a trivial question.

To keep it simple, I have a dataframe like so:

```
   People   Monthly Income
0  Tom      1000
1  Dave     1000
2  Sally    1000 
3  Tom.      100
```

What I want is an elegant way of combining and replacing rows.

So if I wanted both of the roms belonging to Tom to combine into one row, whilst also removing the unwanted row with a period in the name, is there a special function to do this in place or would I have to do it in multiple steps, like add the row's data, then remove unwanted row?

This would be the desired outcome:

```
   People   Monthly Income
0  Tom      1100
1  Dave     1000
2  Sally    1000
```

Edit:

To be clear I want to be able to add any two rows together, which is probably not clear from my given example.

Say if I wanted to add the rows Sally and Dave, whilst removing sally, and just leaving row Dave with the total to produce:

```
   People   Monthly Income
0  Tom      1000
1  Dave     2000
2  Tom.      100
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must define in the most precise way what constitutes two "similar" rows.

Comment: How do you know which rows to combine and which to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to find names in the column `People` that only differ by characters that are not letters. You can adjust the regex pattern in [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to your needs. The pattern `[a-zA-Z]` only works for languages that use latin letters.

```
df.groupby(df.People.str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False), sort=False).sum().reset_index()
```

Out:

```
  People  Monthly Income
0    Tom            1100
1   Dave            1000
2  Sally            1000
```

---

If you want to combine rows 'manually' you can first replace the values with the value you want to keep

```
combine = {'People': {'Sally': 'Dave'}}
df.replace(combine).groupby('People', sort=False).sum().reset_index()
```

Out:

```
  People  Monthly Income
0    Tom            1000
1   Dave            2000
2   Tom.             100
```

For a larger group of values to be combined: Here the rows with 'Dave', 'Sally' and 'Tom.' will be summed in one 'Dave' row

```
combine = {'People': dict.fromkeys(['Sally', 'Tom.'], 'Dave')}
df.replace(combine).groupby('People', sort=False).sum().reset_index()
```

Out:

```
  People  Monthly Income
0    Tom            1000
1   Dave            2100
```

Comment: Thank you for taking to the give me a comprehensive answer Michael, this really helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need

```
df.groupby(['People']).sum()
```

Goodluck in learning pandas!

Comment: This is the right tool, but the names vary a little bit in the example dataframe.